# Interpreting a square root transformation coefficient (regression)

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation

I have the following data in Stata with three variables:
1- High school GPA (out of a 100)
2- job search duration in months
3- Sqr root of job search duration in months

```
dataex HS_gpa log_HS_gpa durationInMonths sqrt_durationInMonths
clear
input float(HS_gpa log_HS_gpa durationInMonths sqrt_durationInMonths)
74.38  4.309187 246 15.684387
   70  4.248495 262 16.186415
   76 4.3307333 112 10.583005
   75  4.317488 190  13.78405
   87  4.465908 470 21.679483
```

I am testing with a bivariate regression the relationship between one's HS GPA and their job search duration, so I ran the regression below:

```
regress durationInMonths HS_gpa

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,905
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 2903)      =     12.21
       Model |  19.4647825         1  19.4647825   Prob > F        =    0.0005
    Residual |   4626.0168     2,903  1.59352973   R-squared       =    0.0042
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0038
       Total |  4645.48158     2,904  1.59968374   Root MSE        =    1.2624

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
durationIn~s |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      HS_gpa |  -.0087986   .0025175    -3.49   0.000    -.0137349   -.0038624
       _cons |   3.029813   .2167351    13.98   0.000     2.604843    3.454783
```

However, I thought that the relationship may not be linear so I created square root variable of the "durationInMonths" variable and ran the same regression again. I further created a log variable of highschool GPA.

The direction of the coefficient is the same, but higher at "-.249" for log_HS_gpa.

```
regress sqrt_durationInMonths log_HS_gpa

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,905
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 2903)      =     14.24
       Model |  2.30839189         1  2.30839189   Prob > F        =    0.0002
    Residual |  470.701254     2,903  .162143043   R-squared       =    0.0049
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0045
       Total |  473.009646     2,904  .162882109   Root MSE        =    .40267

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sqrt_durat~s |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  log_HS_gpa |  -.2499674   .0662488    -3.77   0.000    -.3798667    -.120068
       _cons |   2.564629   .2944605     8.71   0.000     1.987256    3.142001
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```